# gwt - How can I use a 3rd party java library in my gwt project?

Tags: gwt, jar, java

I create a `Editor` gwt project, which works fine.

Now I want to connect the editor's data to a db, so I use a `3rd party database helper tool` for that.

I added the `db tool jar` into my gwt project, no complaint. I also wrote the db related codes using this tool.

But I just can't run my gwt project in the web page.

The error info in gwt console for my web browser is `can't find the source/.xml for the db helper tool`, at least something like that.

How can I manage this?

Thanks

Comment: What does "just can't run" mean? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @onnoweb The error info in gwt console for my web browser is `can't find the source/.xml for the db helper tool`, at least something like that.

Comment: Have you included the jar file in the build path of the project?

Comment: What type of Db do you try to use? GWT is a client-side code. So if you try to use JDBC it will not work. If you ask about HTML5 db than you need add gwt module of helper to your GWT module config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the DB-Tool on the server-side of the code and retrieve the data to the client via an RPC!

See: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC